# Anyway to move the Inspector icon to the top of the Chrome Developer toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspector

I run my monitors in portrait mode, so I have a very high/vertical screen resolution (1440 x 2560). It's really frustrating to have to scroll all the way down to the very bottom of my monitor everytime I need to use the Inspector tool to select an element in the DOM.

Does anyone know of a way to move it to the top of the toolbar like it is in Firebug? (I guess they were trying to keep it from looking similar to Firebug since they moved it to the bottom? -- there doesn't seem to be any reason why this would be better)

Is there a shortcut that can be set up so I can launch the Inspector this way as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> on a Mac

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29532#c15